# React native: Set the coordinates for each item in array

Tags: react-native, coordinates, draggable

I try get the coordinates for each of my Draggaable Items.
Right now I get the coordinates but I only get one value for all the items, but I want a value for each item.

This is my data

```
  const data = [
    {
      name: " ",
      X: 680,
      Y: 80,
      newposX: positionX,
      newposY: positionY,
    },
    {
      name: " ",
      X: 550 ,
      Y: 80,
      newposX: positionX,
      newposY: positionY,
    },
    {
      name: " ",
      X: 550 ,
      Y: 80,
      newposX: positionX,
      newposY: positionY,
    },
  ];
```

Here I print out the data in a draggable element

```
            {data.map((item, key) => (
             <Draggable
                x={item.X}
                y={item.Y}
                renderColor="blue"
                renderSize={50}
                isCircle
                textcolor="#000000"
                renderText={item.name}
                onDragRelease={e => {
                  setPositionY(e.nativeEvent.pageY);
                  setPositionX(e.nativeEvent.pageX);
                }}
                />
              ))}
```

On the "onDragRelease" I set my position by get the coordinates. But here I want too set the postion for each items. but I don't get i works. Do anyone have a clue of what I schould do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `data.map` function you are declaring the index of `item` as variable `key`. You can use this to have a new `setItemPosition` update your data array with new positions.

```
const setItemPosition = (key, x, y) => {
  const updatedData = [...data]
  const item = data[key];
  item.X = x
  item.Y = y
  const updatedData[key] = item
  
  setData(updatedData) // <-- This is your "setState" function for the data array.
}

// Use it in your draggable like this:

            {data.map((item, key) => (
             <Draggable
                x={item.X}
                y={item.Y}
                renderColor="blue"
                renderSize={50}
                isCircle
                textcolor="#000000"
                renderText={item.name}
                onDragRelease={e => {
                  setItemPosition(key, e.nativeEvent.pageX, e.nativeEvent.pageY);
                }}
                />
              ))}
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. It almost works, It  set the coordinates to each item now, so that's perfect. But the draggable Item moves around in an unexpected pattern, what happends is that it moves som extra coordinates from the release point. In your answer you added the updatedData two times. In the second declaure I removed const and just added `updatedData [key] = item`. But Iam not sure if that is right?